# Boost Log record_ostream.hpp won't compile

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I'm attempting to compile example code for Boost Log. I'm getting a compiler error, and assume it has something to do with my compiler flags but am not sure. The code in my main.cpp file (copied directly from the tutorial example) is shown below:

```
/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 16, 2021
 *      Author: ubuntu
 */

#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("sample.log");

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}

int main()
{
    init();
    logging::add_common_attributes();

    using namespace logging::trivial;
    src::severity_logger< severity_level > lg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling from Eclipse on Ubuntu 20.04 and the following is my compiler command:
g++ -std=c++0x -I/usr/local/boost_1_76_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"

The output from the compiler is shown below (truncated to only show first error message):

```
16:00:18 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project SimServe ****
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -I/usr/local/boost_1_76_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
In file included from /usr/local/boost_1_76_0/boost/log/trivial.hpp:24,
                 from ../main.cpp:9:
../main.cpp: In function "int main()":
/usr/local/boost_1_76_0/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:556:5:
**error: expected unqualified-id before "for"
  556 |     for (::boost::log::record rec_var = (logger).open_record((BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(params_seq))); !!rec_var;)\
      |     ^~~**
```

Can anybody please advise what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like copy/paste problems. "./main.cpp: In function "int main()":
/usr/local/boost_1_76_0/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:556:5:
**error: expected unqualified-id before "for"" suggests that an include is done **inside** main. Like your sample shows, that needs to be before main.

Comment: Check if your Boost distribution is intact and whether you're affected by some sort of a macro clash. To do this you would have to inspect the preprocessed output of your code (`-E` command line argument for gcc).